# Karma testing adding unnecessary folders to path

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to do some unit testing and I'm at the end of my rope. I've moved files, rewritten things countless times, and I still can't get the damn thing to work. I've followed [this tutorial](http://mcgivery.com/unit-testing-ionic-app/) exactly and it still doesn't work.

When I run "gulp tests", and I am in my ~/git/mobile directory, I get the following output

```
Josh@DAEDALUS ~/git/mobile (unit-testing)
$ gulp test 
[10:28:40] Using gulpfile c:\Users\Josh\git\mobile\gulpfile.js
[10:28:40] Starting 'test'...
WARN [watcher]: Pattern  "c:/Users/Josh/git/mobile/tests/www/lib/angular/angular.
js" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "c:/Users/Josh/git/mobile/tests/node_modules/angular-moc
ks/angular-mocks.js" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "c:/Users/Josh/git/mobile/tests/www/js/app.js" does not
 match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "c:/Users/Josh/git/mobile/tests/www/js/controller.js" do
es not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "c:/Users/Josh/git/mobile/tests/www/js/services.js" does
not match any file.
 WARN [watcher]: Pattern "c:/Users/Josh/git/mobile/tests/tests/Controllers/contro
 llers.tests.js" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "c:/Users/Josh/git/mobile/tests/tests/Services/services.
tests.js" does not match any file.
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.37 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket --QoOiVt0ZraOpiQ3q
zd with id 22369565
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.003 secs / 0 secs)
[10:28:42] Finished 'test' after 2.19 s
```

See, I don't get why it decides that it wants to add the /tests/ folder out of nowhere. It's not in my directory. For example, a proper path would be c:/users/josh/git/mobile/www/js/controller.js That tests folder isn't there. There is a tests folder in my mobile directory, but it doesn't contain anything but my "my.conf.js" and two subdirectories which contain my test files.
I cannot for the life of me figure out what's wrong. I've tried adding ../, ./, /, or removing that all together from the beginning of my files paths in my.conf.js. 
[Here is the contents of "my.conf.js"](http://hastebin.com/nihuhumibu.js)
[Here is the contents of "gulpfile.js"](http://hastebin.com/uqoromolog.coffee)

Comment: Can you share the directory structure of your app?

Comment: git/mobile/, where mobile has various folders, node_modules, tests, and www being folders inside mobile

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding ../ to my basePath.